# Clojure Pedestal Dataflow Model - correct steps

Tags: clojure, pedestal

Here in the [Pedestal Docs](http://pedestal.io/documentation/application-overview/) it talks about the following steps in the pedestal dataflow:

- Transform
- Effect
- ***Combine***
- Continue
- Emit

Here in a [significant project](https://github.com/rkneufeld/rouge/blob/master/app/src/io/rkn/rouge/behavior.clj) by [one of the authors of Pedestal](https://twitter.com/rkneufeld) - we see the following elements

- transform
- continue
- ***derive***
- effect
- emit

My question is - is derive an undocumented feature of the dataflow? Is it the new name for combine? Is this simply a matter of the Pedestal docs being out of date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, yes, it's just a matter of the docs being out of date. The pedestal authors updated the dataflow quite recently from version 1 to version 2.

Most of the existing documentation refers to version 1 (which has the steps you mention), and last time I checked, the documentation for version 2 was still in progress.

However, there is a [comprehensive pedestal tutorial](http://github.com/pedestal/app-tutorial) available now, which uses version 2 of the dataflow (including `derive`).

In addition to this, Taylor Sando did a [useful write up](http://github.com/taylorSando/pedestal-todo/blob/master/beginners.md) for beginners